# Compilation failure Project Maven Eclipse Java 17

Tags: maven, build, compiler-errors, compilation

I downloaded my application from gitHUB and i uploaded it doing Import-Maven-Existing Maven Projects then i choose as root directory the path of application in local.
After this i tried to build the project doing Maven clean before and it was build success and then i tried to do Maven install and the console gave me these errors:

### COMPILATION ERROR :

> Failed to execute goal
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile[m
> (default-testCompile)on project administration-apis Compilation
> failure: Compilation failure:

I tried to follow some tutorials but i didn't solve the problem,i'm expecting to build and compile my project.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[mre]" and all their linked pages. We need more information about the error, and to see enough of your code to replicate the problem.